# How to change iOS/Android project folders in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to React Native and I want to move `android` and `ios` folders to a folder that I've created named `platforms`. I've moved the folders and ran:

`react-native run-ios --project-path ./platforms/ios`

Got an error about the `../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` script, changed it to `../../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` as I've moved the folder one directory in.

It starts building (it finds the `xcodeproj`) and fails with:

```
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/React Native/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.h:8:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

info #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
```

(since my focus is on iOS, I haven't checked Android)

How can I properly move the `ios` and `android` folders to my custom folder and build React Native app properly?

Comment: I would question why it is you are trying to change the structure, the prior structure is a React Native standard, but apart from that, have you tried successfully building the project prior to moving the folders?

Comment: take a look at [github issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/567)

Comment: if you really need to do this, you can go to `rootProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIos`. here you can modify the path of `react-native run-ios`

Comment: @ChadNehemiah I don't want to clutter the root folder with many files/folders and even by default there is a lot.

Comment: @flix `run-ios` already accepts the project path argument (as, if I omit it, I get an error saying that it can't find the project in the first place). with the correct path it finds the project, but it can't build. I think it has something to do with the header paths (inferring from the error).

Comment: @ChadNehemiah yes, if it's in the default location, it builds and works.